# Hibernate projection on many-to-many property

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, projection

I'm using Hibernate 3.3.2. I have class A, which has a property b, which maps a many-to-many relation to B.

Class A has the following mapping:

```
<set name="b" table="a_b" lazy="true">
   <key column="id_a"/>
   <many-to-many class="B" column="id_b" outer-join="auto" />
</set>
```

I am trying the following:

```
Criteria c = HibernateUtil.getSession().createCriteria(A.class);
ProjectionList pl = Projections.projectionList();
pl.add(Projections.property("id_a"), "id_a");
pl.add(Projections.property("b"), "b");
c.setProjection(pl);
c.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
Object o = c.list();
```

This code doesn't load any instance of B; the element corresponding to b in the returned ArrayList is null. Do you have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided fetchs the list of B entity of a specific A row. You should do the join in the inverse way, fetch B and join A just to restrict the query:

```
Criteria c = HibernateUtil.getSession().createCriteria(B.class);
c.createCriteria("a").add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
List<B> o = (List<B>) c.list();
```

The above code should do the trick.

Comment: The important thing is "in the inverse way"

Answer (score 0):

Since fetchType is lazy you need to create an alias for b: c.createAlias(...) so that hibernate will join A with B.

Comment: I tried c.createAlias("b", "b"), but nothing changed. I suppose it has something to do with the cardinality of the relation.

Comment: Here is the code:`Criteria c = HibernateUtil.getSession().createCriteria(A.class);
ProjectionList pl = Projections.projectionList();
pl.add(Projections.property("id_a"), "id_a");
pl.add(Projections.property("b"), "b");
c.setProjection(pl);
c.createAlias("b", "b");
c.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
Object o = c.list();`

Comment: You are trying to fetch the id of a and the entity b? That will not work. Projections are not for loading entities but for aggregation and fetching specific properties of entities. In your case I don't see the need for Projections. Simply: ...`createCriteria(A.class).createAlias("b").list()`. This will load all A's with their B's.

Comment: The entity A has many properties, so I need to project on a subset of them (I can't modify A). In the previous code I showed only the id. I'd like to load these properties with "b" too.

Comment: Ok, you could also specify which properties of b you want to fetch and then use like an AliasToBeanResultTransformer but for this scenario I would still advice to simply load A's with their B's. I doubt their will be any performance gain using Projections. Keep it simple.